# How can I get the screen size of mobile devices when they hit my web server?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mobile

I want to get the screen size of mobile devices when they hit a URL on my server.

O am already using `echo$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. How can I get the screen size? Can it be done by using jQuery/JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it in javascript then send it up to php:

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
function detect()
{
alert('Screen resolution is '+screen.width+'x'+screen.height+'.');
}
</script>

<a href='#' onclick='detect();return false;'>Detect Screen Resolution</a>
```

Comment: @Ekansh you might check out wurfl mobile device capabilities such as resolution_width and resolution_height. basically you identify the device id and search thru their datafile and it spits out info on the device

Comment: typically they are server-side like php as the webserver picks up the ids from the mobile browsers hitting them. then php acts accordingly to the device capabilities

Comment: go to that link. download a repository and use php or .net server side

Comment: i have downloaded wurfl but it is only one xml file

Comment: its  a 20 MB xml data file. now go get the php stuff from their site

Comment: i have downloaded php stuff from site but how can i configure that with my php page

Comment: they have documentation dont they

Comment: Script is running properly but not getting correct screen size of Handsets some times

Comment: can u add the definitions? is it slow cuz that xml was so huge

Comment: yes it is of size approx 21mb .. what can i do for getting more exact results , i have already using latest version of that xml file but it is not giving exact screen match for mostly handsets having bigger screens??

Comment: i was reading last nite how you could loadup more nodes in the xml if you know the values

Comment: value means handsets ids,version ??

Comment: yeah create your own phones or groups or categories or generics/fallbacks

Comment: so this is the last option or is there any other API from where i can get XML file having missing nodes??

Comment: you've gotta know that 50 new phones hit the streets every day

Comment: well i think its atleast 51 phones every day :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml
hope this may be useful to detect!!