# Check Small Resolution for a Mobile Website

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I am developing a mobile website and I used CSS in order to change the layout design when the screen width ranges from 150px - 480px. However, when I testing to the actual phone, the screen layout for desktop I am seeing instead of the layout that I've used with CSS.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487119/how-can-i-get-the-screen-size-of-mobile-devices-when-they-hit-my-web-server), I should get the screen width, but I don't know how to access it and put a layout statement if the screen width ranges from 150px - 480px only.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 480px) {
#header .navbar ul li a {
    font-size:15px;     
}

#content .apk {
    padding-bottom:5px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;       
}

#content .apk img{
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

#content .apk p {
    margin-top:-20px;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#444;
}

#content .apk .submit {
    margin-top:-10px;
    margin-left:100px;
    resize:horizontal;
    width:32%;

}

#footer h5 {
    font-size: 14px;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS media query to do that:

```
@media all and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    /* insert specific CSS here */
}
```

See these articles:

- http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/introduction-to-css-media-queries.html
- http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/responsive-layouts-using-css-media-queries/
- http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Actually this is the code I am referring that I used from CSS